# allow less secure app access in Yahoo mail

Tags: email, imap, yahoo, yahoo-mail

I need to allow less secure app access in Yahoo but I can't find the button :(

[image: see setting section]

Any ideas ?

Regards,

Comment: That is what ‘Generate App Password’ is for.  Use that as your password.  That is the less secure option.

Comment: Thank you Max for your reply, when I click on it it shows me selectbox of devices what should I do ?

Comment: Probably doesn't matter which one you pick, as long as you can copy/paste the password.

Comment: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-third-party-passwords-sln15241.html
Generate and manage third-party app passwords

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally found it,

Go to ‘Generate App Password’ then select MacMail(in my case I use it) then copy past the generated code instead of your password.

Comment: Valid as of November 2021; generate the "app password" once and it'll keep working; the server connection URL is `imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert`.

Comment: As of 2022/06/27 this doesn't work anymore, when you click Generate password, a pop up says "Sorry, this feature is not available right now!"

Comment: @Imad Do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: @Daniel Griffin, not yet.

Comment: @Imad I'm working on this right now too!  I'll bookmark this and hopefully we can keep each other updated if we find something that works.  Please tag me if you have any luck and I'll do the same!

Comment: @Imad, I got this to work, see my answer below.  Although I was able to successfully generate an app password, so not sure why you're getting that error.

Comment: @Imad, I have a generic yahoo account with no company name. I decided to use Gmail and everything worked for me. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: @DanielGriffin that's curious, perhaps a regional feature/bug? I'm in France.

Comment: @Imad I'm in the US, so it's possible. I have a theory that it's not valid for new accounts. I had just created the account when I tried to do it. This would be to minimize bot spam.

Answer (score 4):

### Tested and working (2021)

*The answer already provided by @zackzulg (see below). I have extended it.*

'Less secure apps/services' don't support Yahoo's own sign-in method. An app password is a long, randomly generated code that gives a non-Yahoo app permission to access your Yahoo account.

Some older, third-party email apps (that do not use our Yahoo branded sign-in page) require you to enter a single password for login credentials. To access your Yahoo Mail account on these apps, you'll need to generate and use an app password.

1. Log into your Yahoo email account
2. Click your name on top right
3. Click the text **'Account info'**
4. Select **'Generate App Password'**
5. Click **'Get Started'**. if its your first time
6. Add your **"App's name"** (Any name, for your reference)
7. Click **'Generate Password'**
8. Copy this password and go to your app and instead of yahoo password enter this one.

#### What you need to know about 'Generate App Password'

1. You'll only need to provide this code once to sign in to your third-party app.
2. It does not replace your normal password.
3. If you are stop using the app you can delete this password from the same place.

Comment: Hey, I'm working on something for my job with Yahoo mail. I am using the approach you mention here and I am able to successfully connect with SMTP but the incoming connection isn't working. I've been trying to debug this for hours and haven't had issues with any other mail service. So when I found your answer I figured I'd see if you had encountered any issues because it is the only recent resource I've come across. Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Honestly i haven't tested this myself. One of our client had issue not connecting to Yahoo Mail and after all the credential troubleshooting, i suggested this and they said it works. The client had business yahoo account. whats yours?

Comment: oh ok, no problem. I'm just at my wit's end so figured I'd see if you may have known any further info.

My email account is just a normal account, I did create it about a month ago but the SMTP connection works so I doubt the account age is keeping the IMAP from working.

Comment: I get the error message "Sorry, this feature is not available right now!" with the HTTP error code "401 Unauthorized". Yahoo is very disappointing like Gmail who removed password authentication.

Comment: @baptx I am sorry! I don't use yahoo. That troubleshoot is for my client.

Answer (score 2):

For yahoo smtp configuration for used on third party app,need to generate app password. below step follow

1 Please login to your yahoo account and after login top right side Username show, please hover  mouse on this username ,Click on Account information Link.

2 Go to Account Security tab, Go to App password Section, and Click on Generate and manage app passwords, Type app name and click on generate Password.

**This is your smtp email password**

Now set yahoo smtp configuration

Smtp Address : smtp.mail.yahoo.com

Smtp Port: 587

Smtp Username: Your yahoo Email

Smtp Password: Password is which you generate app password

Enable SSL: True

i get this information from this link

http://w3teachers.com/javascript-problem/How-to-set-up-Yahoo-smtp-configuration-for-use-on-third-party-app

Answer (score 1):

This works as of June 29, 2022.  I am using the latest version of java mail (1.6.2) - it has since moved to jakarta and angus so those jars  may also work but I didn't try them.  Get the jar [here](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases/download/JAVAMAIL-1_6_2/javax.mail.jar).

1. Set up your smtp settings to use port 465, SMTPS, and STARTTLS with outgoing server smtp.mail.yahoo.com
2. Generate an app password in Yahoo and use this in place of your usual password.  Do this by logging into your yahoo mail account, click on your profile pic, and in the drop down choose "Account Info."  Choose "Account Security" and on this page select "Generate App Password".  I read something that said you need to use the company name in the app name so that's what I did.

Comment: Amber, how can the "Generate app password" be only working for you at this point? You don't get "this feature is not available right now"? And what is "the company name"?

Comment: @chocalaca I do not get" this feature is not available right now" - It is still available today 7/26/22.  Not sure if that makes any difference, but I have "Account Key" turned on.  When I click "Generate App password" I'm prompted for an "app name".  This is where I used the name of the company I work for.

Comment: Thanks @Amber. So "Account Key" is for account access via mobile, right? Each time your project logs in, are you prompted on your mobile to confirm?

Comment: So @Amber I got "Account key" but it didn't change anything. Maybe your company has some special account

Comment: So I actually just called yahoo (who knew?). The tech said they are having issues with that feature on their end...likely something about enhancing the passwords generated (he was challenging to understand). He suggested waiting 1-2 days before trying it again. We'll see....

Comment: I think I'm only prompted on my mobile when I log in to my email from a new computer.  My company is tiny, we don't have any special account that I'm aware of.  I'm using my personal email address to test this with, but it also worked for our QA dept. Hopefully it will work for you in a few days, good luck, getting email settings right can be challenging. :-/

Answer (score 0):

after some time (in my case 2 months) that password stops working and you need to generate a new password for your app. otherwise you get the "too many bad auth attemps" error.